# How to get MIN of a range, along with a 2nd cell in same row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Thank you to the Excel gurus of stackoverflow for helping me with what seems to be an impossible project. I have another question:

I have 2 worksheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

`Sheet1` has a list of product codes in `A` and a formula to get the lowest price from `Sheet2` in `B`:

```
A      B      C
A100   $10
A200   $12
A300   $45
```

`Sheet2` has a list of product codes, prices, and descriptions:

```
A      B      C
A100   $20    Product One
A100   $10    Product Two
A100   $12    Product Three
A100   $0     Not Found
A200   $25    Product A
A200   $12    Product B
etc, etc, etc
```

In `Sheet1`, column `B`, I'm using the following formula to find the lowest non-zero price:

```
=MIN(IF('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$20000=A1,IF('Sheet2'!$B$1:$B$20000>0,'Sheet2'!$B$1:$B$20000)))
```

How can this be modified to also grab the description in column `C` and place it in `Sheet1` column `C`?

As always, thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Any intermediate columns are allowed or strictly prohibited?

Comment: As far as creating new columns? I can most likely do that if necessary. Also, I just modified my question a bit to provide more clarity as to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: according to your formula, you use sheet `U&C` - what is located there?

Comment: U&C should actually read "Sheet2" .. I removed by actual sheet names for simplicity's sake. I edited my post to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer) Put the following in C1:

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!C"&MATCH(A1&MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$20000=A1,IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000>0,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000))),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$20000&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000,0)),"No price / description found")`

and don't forget to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!). Error handling is included as well.

In case 1-cell solution with combined price AND description required - use this monster:

`=IFERROR("$"&MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$20000=A1,IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000>0,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000)))&": "&INDIRECT("Sheet2!C"&MATCH(A1&MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$20000=A1,IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000>0,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000))),Sheet2!$A$1:$A$20000&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20000,0)),"No price / description found")`

Sample file is available as well: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnb3ov7o1s2sper/PriceWithDescr.xlsx

Comment: WOW. Both of those worked perfectly! Thank you so much for taking the time to come up with this!

Comment: @JeffBrady happy to help pal) BTW like your Qs, they require non-trivial solutions)))

Comment: just trying to keep you guys on your toes! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INDEX/MATCH` solution, e.g. for C1

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C$1:C$20000,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A$1:A$20000=A1)*(Sheet2!B$1:B$20000=B1),0))`

confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Answer (score 0):

Because both your Product Code and Price columns within Sheet2 will likely have duplicate values, I'd recommend creating a unique value in Sheet2 that you can use to differentiate between different price/product code combinations. Here's how I addressed this:

**Step 1 - Insert a New Column in Sheet2**

I added a new column before the current column A with the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2,"-",C2)
```

This revision will now yield the following values for Sheet2:

```
A          B          C          D
A100-20    A100       20         Product One   
A100-10    A100       10         Product Two
A100-12    A100       12         Product Three
A100-0     A100       0          Not Found
```

**Step 2 - Enter a new Formula in column C in Sheet2**

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2),Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE)
```

This will look up the combination of values in columns A and B from Sheet1 from the data in Sheet2. Additional error-checking could be added to ignore zero-priced products, but I have not included this in my formula as you already accounted for this in your previous formula in Sheet1 column B. When I tested it, this produced the correct description.

If you can't modify the worksheet to this extent, you could also use an iterative VBA-based solution, which I'd be happy to demonstrate if necessary.

Good luck!